# Вывод в консоль с форматированием в виде таблицы

Tags: c#, консоль, типы-данных, форматирование, c#-8.0

Изучаю C# по книге Марка Прайса (c# 8 и .net core. разработка и оптимизация), завершил вторую главу и не могу выполнить практическое задание, т к не разобрался в форматировании, не вдупляю. Не понимаю как отсортировать данные таблицы, чтобы они были строго под своими столбцами. Помогите мне пожалуйста выполнить это задание (намекните, сделайте и тд):

> ...Создайте проект консольного приложения Exercise02, которое выводит количество
> байтов в памяти для каждого из следующих числовых типов, а также минимальное
> и максимальное допустимые значения: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double и decimal.

вот мой код (don't laugh))))

```
        Console.WriteLine("Type\tByte(s) of memory\tMin\tMax");

        Console.WriteLine(
           format:"{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
           "sbyte", 
           $"{sizeof(sbyte)}",
           $"{sbyte.MinValue:N0}", 
           $"{sbyte.MaxValue:N0}");
       
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "short",
            $"{sizeof(short)}",
            $"{short.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{short.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "ushort",
            $"{sizeof(ushort)}",
            $"{ushort.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{ushort.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "int",
            $"{sizeof(int)}",
            $"{int.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{int.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "uint",
            $"{sizeof(uint)}",
            $"{uint.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{uint.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "long",
            $"{sizeof(long)}",
            $"{long.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{long.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "ulong",
            $"{sizeof(ulong)}",
            $"{ulong.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{ulong.MaxValue:N0}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "float",
            $"{sizeof(float)}",
            $"{float.MinValue:E}", 
            $"{float.MaxValue:E}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "double",
            $"{sizeof(double)}",
            $"{double.MinValue:E}", 
            $"{double.MaxValue:E}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", 
            "decimal",
            $"{sizeof(decimal)}",
            $"{decimal.MinValue:N0}", 
            $"{decimal.MaxValue:N0}");`
```

Выглядеть должно вот так:
[image: Выглядеть должно вот так:]

Comment: с чем конкретно возникает проблема? Где код твоих попыток решить задачу?

Comment: Не понимаю как отформатировать данные таблицы, чтобы все они были строго под своими столбцами

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос мой безграмотный код))

Comment: а картинка с выводом - это как сейчас или как надо?

Comment: это как надо, я сделал скрин из книги

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я просто оставлю это здесь...

```
var types = new[] 
{
    typeof(sbyte), 
    typeof(short),
    typeof(ushort),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(uint),
    typeof(long),
    typeof(ulong),
    typeof(float),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(decimal),
};


// Отступы каждых столбцов (10 первый, 20 второй, по 30 два последних) + 5 символов "|"
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10 + 20 + 30 + 30 + 5));
Console.WriteLine("|{0,10}|{1,20}|{2,30}|{3,30}|", "Type", "Byte(s) of memory", "Min", "Max");
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10 + 20 + 30 + 30 + 5));

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
    var min = type.GetField("MinValue").GetValue(null); // Берем нужное поле из типа
    var max = type.GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(null); // и забираем его значение

    Console.WriteLine("|{0,10}|{1,20}|{2,30}|{3,30}|", type.Name.ToLower(), size, min, max);
}
```

Вывод:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      Type|   Byte(s) of memory|                           Min|                           Max|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     sbyte|                   1|                          -128|                           127|
|     int16|                   2|                        -32768|                         32767|
|    uint16|                   2|                             0|                         65535|
|     int32|                   4|                   -2147483648|                    2147483647|
|    uint32|                   4|                             0|                    4294967295|
|     int64|                   8|          -9223372036854775808|           9223372036854775807|
|    uint64|                   8|                             0|          18446744073709551615|
|    single|                   4|                -3,4028235E+38|                 3,4028235E+38|
|    double|                   8|      -1,7976931348623157E+308|       1,7976931348623157E+308|
|   decimal|                  16|-79228162514264337593543950335| 79228162514264337593543950335|
```

Также оставлю это: [Составное форматирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Всякие "рюшечки" и другие косяки думаю поправите/сделаете без труда самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)))))

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю что вопрос уже старый но для тех кто сейчас учится по этой книге (такие как я) хочу напомнить что автор оставил в начале книги ссылку на репозиторий на гитхабе с кодами для всех проектов (включая этот) всех глав. Там же можно найти код который автор посчитал верным и правильным для данного уровня знаний C#.

Если что, вот код:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace Exercise02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            WriteLine("Type    Byte(s) of memory               Min                            Max");
            WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            WriteLine($"sbyte   {sizeof(sbyte),-4} {sbyte.MinValue,30} {sbyte.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"byte    {sizeof(byte),-4} {byte.MinValue,30} {byte.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"short   {sizeof(short),-4} {short.MinValue,30} {short.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"ushort  {sizeof(ushort),-4} {ushort.MinValue,30} {ushort.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"int     {sizeof(int),-4} {int.MinValue,30} {int.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"uint    {sizeof(uint),-4} {uint.MinValue,30} {uint.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"long    {sizeof(long),-4} {long.MinValue,30} {long.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"ulong   {sizeof(ulong),-4} {ulong.MinValue,30} {ulong.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"float   {sizeof(float),-4} {float.MinValue,30} {float.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"double  {sizeof(double),-4} {double.MinValue,30} {double.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine($"decimal {sizeof(decimal),-4} {decimal.MinValue,30} {decimal.MaxValue,30}");
            WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```