# Реализовать вывод строк после считывания из файла, и Конвертации данных

Tags: c#, вывод, типы-данных, конвертация

Всем привет.
Первоначально задача стояла в том, чтобы реализовать считывание данных из файла, определение типа данных, и дополнение данных строкой с указанием типа данных, а так заменой (_) на пробел.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, по выводу в консоль в виде таблицы.
Программа выполняет считывание данных из файла.
Сортирует по номеру и конвертирует данные в соответствующий тип из string.
Но при выводе в консоль, данные не разделяются столбцами и выглядят смешанно, а требуется произвести вывод по столбцам.

```
№ Серия Наименование        Дополнение

1 677492 12Тм_54 Допол

1 Привет 76 1з

7 654 Это Твоё

2 Тестовое -=-=-= СимволыИлиНет?

0 Задание ЉµЉ 1787_-_?

2147483747 Удачи На_полях Правосудия
```

Вот код программы.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;
                    
class Program
{
public record Item(long Number, IEnumerable<string> OtherData);

static void Main(string[] args)
{

        
//Загружаю все элементы из файла
var items = LoadItemsFromFile("file.txt");

//Сначала сортирую элементы по номеру, а затем прохожусь по ним циклом
foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(x => x.Number))
{
//Каждый элемент "определяю" и вывожу на консоль
DefineItemTypeAndWrite(item);
}
}

private static IEnumerable<Item> LoadItemsFromFile(string path)
=> File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x =>
{
var data = x.Split();
return new Item(long.Parse(data[0]), data.Skip(1));
});

private static Type[] types = new[]
{
        typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
        typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
        typeof(int), typeof(uint),
        typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
        typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal),
    };

    private static void DefineItemTypeAndWrite(Item item)
    {
        //Вывожу номер, т.к по нему никаких проверок не надо делать
        Console.Write($"№: {item.Number} ");

        //По каждому элементу(серия, наименование, дополнение) пытаюсь подобрать тип от базового
        //sbyte до string и при первой попытке вывожу его
        foreach (string data in item.OtherData)
        {
            var type = types.FirstOrDefault(x => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(x)?.IsValid(data) == true) ?? typeof(string);
            // Если надо преобразовать, то: var value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type)?.ConvertFromString(data);
            Console.Write($" {data} - {type.Name}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1303271/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , уточните пожалуйста, а как данный код можно применить к вашему решению по определению типов ?

Comment: Внимание на строку `Console.WriteLine("|{0,10}|{1,20}|{2,30}|{3,30}|", type.Name.ToLower(), size, min, max);`, а точнее на `{0,10}`, где первое значение - индекс того, что принимается 2-м++ параметром метода (`size, min, max` - size - это 0, min - 1, max - 2. Параметры разные, да и любое кол-во может быть), а второе - то, сколько символов должно занимать. И да, не копируйте бездумно код!! Вот это к примеру `File.WriteAllText` зачем вам? В моем примере это лишь для того было, чтоб онлайн код прочитал дальше из файла, не более.. А вы сейчас постоянно переписываете файл...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да вы правы сюда перенес код , из первоначального варианта. В VS подправил. Спасибо. Касательно решения не смог додуматься как сделать с текущим решением вывод по столбцам, поэтому задал вопрос .

Comment: Вы хотите, чтоб мы за вас все задание решили или что? Я понимаю, новичок и все дела, ок, но это ведь не повод вырубить голову и по каждому чиху идти и просить помощь... Подумайте хоть немного, я выше уже дал вам решение и расписал как должно быть. Ок, давайте еще упрощу вам жизнь: `Console.Write($" {data} - {type.Name}");` -> `Console.Write("| {0, -20}", $"{data} - {type.Name}");` (`-` означает то, что текст будет позиционирован по левому краю), с номерами я надеюсь вы в состоянии самостоятельно сделать? И да, как я говорил в том комментарии - разделите логику получения данных и их вывод (SRP)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, огромное спасибо Евгений, как раз методом проб и ошибок дошел до аналогичного решения только : Console.Write("|{0,15}|{1,15}|", $" {data} - {type.Name}","\t"); , но выравние было не совсем удачным .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый ответ получился такой:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    public record Item(long Number, IEnumerable<string> OtherData);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Загружаю все элементы из файла
        var items = LoadItemsFromFile("file.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("|{0,-15}||{1,-25}||{2,-25}||{3,-25}|", " №", " Серия", " Наименование", " Дополнение");
        //Сначала сортирую элементы по номеру, а затем прохожусь по ним циклом
        foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(x => x.Number))
        {
            //Каждый элемент "определяю" и вывожу на консоль
            DefineItemTypeAndWrite(item);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Item> LoadItemsFromFile(string path)
        => File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x =>
        {
            var data = x.Split();
            return new Item(long.Parse(data[0]), data.Skip(1));
        });

    private static Type[] types = new[]
    {
        typeof(sbyte), typeof(byte),
        typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
        typeof(int), typeof(uint),
        typeof(long), typeof(ulong),
        typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal),
    };

    private static void DefineItemTypeAndWrite(Item item)
    {
        //Вывожу номер
        Console.Write("|{0,-15}|",$" {item.Number} ");
            
        foreach (string data in item.OtherData)
        {
            var type = types.FirstOrDefault(x => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(x)?.IsValid(data) == true) ?? typeof(string);
            // Если надо преобразовать, то: var value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type)?.ConvertFromString(data);
            Console.Write("|{0, -25}|", $" {data.Replace("_"," ")} - {type.Name}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прикладывайте всю тестовую информацию, том числе и консольный вывод в текстовые блоки. Это упрощает использование и поиск

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо , скорректировал первичную задачу ) Консольный вывод приложен ранее)